# What license is the Stack Exchange API released under? MIT?

Tags: support, documentation

Are there any license requirements the Stack Exchange API?

Which license is it released under?

If I were to develop an app, would I have to credit Stack Exchange API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about a number of things here, so let me see if I can explain them all:

- The code powering the API is (presumably) written in C# and is closed-source.
- The *content* provided by the API is licensed under a Creative Commons (w/ attribution) license.
- The applications / libraries that *use* the API can be under any license you choose.
- The logos, domain names, and trademarks are owned by Stack Overflow Inc. There are special restrictions on their use.

Note that apart from the above (the CC-license and trademark restrictions), you are not required to mention Stack Overflow or give credit to anyone.

Comment: However why would you not credit Stack Overflow Inc for creating the API which enabled your application in the first place? :)

Comment: @Diago: Exactly... although some applications (like StackList) are not *centered* around the API. (Although they use it.)

Comment: So if a web app (subscribers to pay) needed a question/answer/discussion system (centred around specific resources made available to its subscribers) could it use the Stack Exchange API to provide this? I'm a non-dev and am a little unclear as to the implications. Thanks.

Comment: @David: Not really. The API only provides read access to the content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see there are some other Q&A type systems available so will look into using these for the web app.